# Laplace transform of a one-sided full-wave rectified...

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Here's the problem:
[Follow the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfPwt.png)

Can someone please explain how to start this problem? I have been staring at it for a long time and I'm not sure where to begin.

where $\displaystyle F_1(s) =  Aw\frac{1+e^{-sT/2}}{s^2+w^2}$ "bear with me while I format this properly"

Comment: How do they define this "one-sided full wave" thingie?

Comment: Do you mean a electronic circuit?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to integrate directly:

$$F_1(s)=\int_0^{\infty}(u(t)-u(t-\frac{T}{2}))A\sin(\omega t)e^{-st}dt$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac{T}{2}} A\sin(\omega t)e^{-st} dt$$
$$=A\omega(\frac{1 + e^\frac{-T s}{2}}{s^2 + \omega^2})$$

where $\omega T=2\pi$.

$$~$$
$$~$$

[image]

Comment: thank you, I can't believe I didn't see this before...